# Dimension of vector spaces involving differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let V denotes  the vector space $C^5[a,b]$ over $\mathbb  R $, and $W=\{f\in V:\frac{d^4f}{dt^4}+2\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}-f=0\}$.Then

1. $\dim(V)=\infty$ and $\dim(W)=\infty$
2. $\dim(V)=\infty$ and $\dim(W)=4$
3. $\dim(V)=6$ and $\dim(W)=5$
4. $\dim(V)=5$ and $\dim(W)=4$

I have no idea how to solve this problem.Does $C^5[a,b]$ denote the set of 5 times continuously differentiable functions on [a,b]. so dimension(V)=5. Is it ? is the dim(W)=4? Please someone help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the dimension of a vector space, find a basis and "count" its size.

All polynomals are in $V=C^5[a,b]$, especially $x^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Because these are linear independent the dimension of $V$ is $\infty$.

Considering $W$: If we solve the differential equation, we integrate it in a way. Every time we integrate it we obtain an integration constant. Thus a differential equation of order 4 has usually a solution space of dimension 4. (I am not so sure about non linear differential equations but this one is linear.)

PS: Yes. $C^5[a,b] := \{f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \vert f \text{ is 5 times continuously differentiable} \}$ denotes the set of 5 times continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$.